# Choose the proper DbProviderFactory in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dbproviderfactories

I have a .net core library that needs a `DbProviderFactory` passed into a service as a dependency.  It should be SQL Server for the foreseeable future, so I thought I could do something like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyService>(di=>new MyService(SqlClientFactory.Instance));
```

... but I have multiple db connection strings in my appsettings.json file, and I don't see a mechanism to tell the `Instance` which connection to use.

How do I configure the `DbProviderFactory` to use the proper connection and connection string?  There's no concept of a "name" for a connection or provider in the appsettings file.

Comment: You could try reading the appropriate connection string manually from appsettings and then manually setting it for each connection.

Comment: @SimonKatanski sorry, I mistyped; the dependency is a DbProviderFactory, not a DbConnectionFactory.

Comment: DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient");

Answer (score 3):

The connection string settings from the config has a place a [provider property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.connectionstringsettings.providername?view=netcore-2.0#System_Configuration_ConnectionStringSettings_ProviderName).  You can use it as follows given the right providers are configured locally:

> [System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty("providerName", 
>   DefaultValue=Mono.Cecil.CustomAttributeArgument)] public string
>   ProviderName { get; set; }

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Example" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
         connectionString="Data Source=1.1.1.1;Integrated Security=True"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Which can be called like so:

```
DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(settings.ProviderName);
```

Normally if all you have is a DBConnection, you can create a helper method to retrieve the ProviderFactory:

```
public static DbProviderFactory GetProviderFactory(DbConnection connection)
{
    DbProviderFactory providerFactory = null;
    Type connectionType = connection.GetType();
    BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public;

    // Check for DbConnection.DbProviderFactory
    PropertyInfo providerFactoryInfo = connectionType.GetProperty("DbProviderFactory", flags);
    if (providerFactoryInfo != null)
        providerFactory = (DbProviderFactory)providerFactoryInfo.GetValue(connection, null);

    // Check for DbConnection.ConnectionFactory.ProviderFactory
    if (providerFactory == null)
    {
        PropertyInfo connectionFactoryInfo = connectionType.GetProperty("ConnectionFactory", flags);
        object connectionFactory = connectionFactoryInfo.GetValue(connection, null);
        providerFactoryInfo = connectionFactory.GetType().GetProperty("ProviderFactory", flags);
        providerFactory = (DbProviderFactory)providerFactoryInfo.GetValue(connectionFactory, null);
    }

    // No match
    if (providerFactory == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("ProviderFactory not found for connection");

    return providerFactory;
}
```

However .NET core doesn't include reflection, so this won't work out of the box.

Comment: .net core doesn't use a config file with a connectionStrings section.  I don't see how this applies.

Comment: .net core has many ways to implement and use configuration, including appsettings and web.config style file formats, as mentioned in @Parrish Husband 's response.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1